# Looking for an alternative solution for the mutilated chessboard problem

Tags: puzzle, alternative-proof

> Given a mutilated chessboard where two diagonally opposite squares are missing (the unmutilated version of it has $64$ squares), and given $31$ domino pieces, is it possible to cover the entire chessboard with the dominoes?

This is a classic problem and has a very popular solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem#Solution.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: The given impossibility argument (effectively: *You'd need $31$ squares in each color, but the board has only $30$ squares in one of the colors.*) is tough to beat. What kind of alternative approach did you have in mind?

Comment: Any kind of alternative solution would be nice!.